# Determine if point is inside polygon

Tags: algorithm, polygon, vertex

Currently I am using the ray casting algorithm, however it has some limitations like when the ray passes a vertex it's impossible to determine whether it's inside or not.

What algorithm can I use that will always work in any kind of polygon?

Comment: [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a03-_inclusion.html) might help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine whether a 2D Point is within a Polygon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon)

Comment: integer or floating point numbers?

Comment: @maxim1000 Doesn't really matter, can be float can be integer depending on which one is easier/more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You can select ray direction depending on polygon itself so that it doesn't cross any vertex.

**For integer coordinates** it would be enough to cast a ray along `(1,0.5/deltaX)`, where `deltaX` is the maximum difference between x-coordinates of polygon vertices. The first point with integer coordinates on the ray will be its start. The next one will have x-coordinate `startX+2*deltaX` which is outside of the polygon and cannot be its vertex. With exact arithmetic you can robustly determine whether the point inside or outside.

**For floating point numbers** exact arithmetic is a problem, so you want the ray to be as far from polygon vertices as possible. For this you can calculate direction to every polygon vertex `atan2(y[n]-y,x[n]-x)` and sort the vertices by it. Then select the biggest difference between neighbor vertices in this sorted sequence and cast the ray between them.